# Unknown adapter: json_api. Valid adapters are: [":fragmentcache", ":json", ":flattenjson", ":null", ":jsonapi"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have rails4 running with active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc2) gem. Today I start developing the api for my client device. I run rspec test, It gave me this error

```
ArgumentError:
   Unknown adapter: json_api. Valid adapters are: [":fragmentcache", ":json", ":flattenjson", ":null", ":jsonapi"].
```

My config:

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def initialize(object, options = {})
    ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
    super(object, options)
  end
end
```

I check the gem It is still 0.10.0.rc2. so no change in the gem list. I wonder what can cause this problem ?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from this thread https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/993. my problem was that I have the 'API' acronym in my config/inflections.rb.

```
inflect.acronym 'RSA'
inflect.acronym 'API'
```

The :json_api adapter will actuall be converted to a class. As **api** will be translated to **API** then AMS will not be able to find something like this JsonAPI.

To solve this I have to put the class directly as below:

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def initialize(object, options = {})
    ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi
    super(object, options)
  end
end
```